# Filter query by given parameter or blank if nothing provided

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a working solution, but I was wondering if there was a better way to get the same result.

The scenario:

User interface has a search filter that resolves to a GUID.  So if they wanted to search for all records associated with customer `John Doe`, they would type in John Doe and before the final query is executed John Doe is resolved to John Doe's customer_id.  So if the customer_id is `XYZ-456`, the query would be:

```
SELECT id AS item_id FROM items WHERE items.customer_id = 'XYZ-456';
```

This would return the item ids which would then go through another process to provide the user with the full search results.

But obviously the user might not choose a filter at all.  Rather than insert the entire `WHERE` parameter, I've gone with the following solution:

```
SELECT id AS item_id FROM items WHERE items.customer_id LIKE '%$customer_id%';
```

So if nothing is given, it resolves to:

```
SELECT id AS item_id FROM items WHERE items.customer_id LIKE '%%';
```

Which will return all items (the desired result).

Really, this works fine, but technically their is always the theoretical issue of the following customer_ids `XYZ-456`, `EXYZ-4567`, where the shorter of the two ids would return items for both customer_ids.

So is there a "right" way to say "return all results where field = 'X' but if 'X' is blank, return everything instead of nothing?"

Comment: Just to know: there's any reason why you don't do this with a programming language?

Comment: Do which part?  Write out the clause with a conditional statement?  Because I prefer to minimize as much code as possible, DB or programming.  Basically the same reason I use MySQL functions like YEAR() instead of deriving the year in code and passing it in.  Because the DB can do it, and because I know if something goes wrong, it's with the query, not with php and mysql not getting along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where items.customer_id = '$customer_id' or '$customer_id' = ''
```

logic like that also works well when filtering on multiple optional criteria.

edit--a similar way

```
where '$customer_id' in (items.customer_id, '')
```

Comment: Oh nice.  Where blank equals blank.  Let me try that out.

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly the simple but outside of my creative reach solution I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the theoretical fun, because I would most certainly solve this in PHP.

```
SELECT id AS item_id FROM items WHERE items.customer_id LIKE IF("$customer_id" = "", "%%", "$customer_id");
```

No idea if this works, but I'm quite curious.

Comment: +1 For Throwing out an untested idea that worked.  I'm going with chris for the answer, since his doesn't require using a function (and thus should be more cross-db reliable), but your idea is solid and I'm surprised it didn't even cross my mind.   Thanks.